# C++ multithreading: QSocketNotifier:Socket notifiers cannot be enabled or disabled from another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have 3 threads.
The main thread (for my GUI) -> worker thread A -> worker thread B

In worker thread B (in my code called recognitionThread) I am trying to start a process and write data to that process. The process is supposed to start my python virtual environment (this part works) and execute some commands in that environment (that doesn t work).

When I try to write data to that process I get: 
Socket notifiers cannot be enabled or disabled from another thread

I think I kind of understand what the problem is, but not totally and have no clue about how to solve my issue.

Those are the relevant parts of my code:

- recognitionClass.cpp:

  ```
    QProcess recognitionClass::p;

   recognitionClass::recognitionClass(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
  {
       startPythonVirtualEnv();
  }

  void recognitionClass::startPythonVirtualEnv()
  {
      qRegisterMetaType<QProcess::ProcessError>("QProcess::ProcessError");
  params<<"-f"<<"-c"<<"python2"<< "/home/John/Desktop/python.log";
      qDebug()<<"parameters: "<<params;

      if(p.state()==2)
      {qDebug()<<"python virtualenv already running";}
      else
      {
          p.start("script", params);
          qDebug()<<"started process";
          while(!p.waitForStarted())
          {qDebug()<<"waiting for virtualenv to be ready";}
      } 
  }

  recognitionClass::person recognitionClass::runRecognitionScript()
  {
        person persStrObj;

        qRegisterMetaType<QProcess::ProcessError>("QProcess::ProcessError");
        connect(&p, &QProcess::errorOccurred, qApp, &QApplication::aboutQt );

         qint64 successFailWrite;
         delay();
         qDebug()<<"before p.write()";
         successFailWrite = p.write("import imp; foo = imp.load_source('myTest', '/home/John/openface/demos/recognitionClass.py'); from myTest import recognitionClass; myClassObj = recognitionClass(); print myClassObj.recognize('/home/John/Desktop/camera.jpg');");
         qDebug()<<"after p.write()";
         delay();

         qDebug()<<"started process, result write op: "<< successFailWrite;

  }
  ```
- recognitionClass.h:

  ```
       class recognitionClass : public QObject
       {
           Q_OBJECT
       private:
           struct person{
               QString persName;
               double persCertitude;
           };

           static QProcess p;
           QStringList params;

       public:
           explicit recognitionClass(QObject *parent = nullptr);
           struct person runRecognitionScript();
           void startPythonVirtualEnv();
           void stopPythonVirtualEnv();
           void delay();
       signals:

       public slots:
           double recognizePerson();
       };
  ```
- webcamclass.cpp:

  ```
       webcamClass::webcamClass(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
       {
           recognizePerson=false;

           //setup recognition thread
           recognitionThread = new QThread(this);
           recognitionClObj = new recognitionClass();

           connect( recognitionThread, SIGNAL(started()), recognitionClObj, SLOT(recognizePerson()) );
           recognitionClObj->moveToThread(recognitionThread);
       }


       void webcamClass:: getVideoFrame()
       {
           static cv::VideoCapture cap(CV_CAP_ANY);
           cv::Mat imgFrame;

           if( !cap.isOpened() )
           {
               qDebug()<< "Could not initialize capturing...\n";
           }

           while(1)
           {
               cap >> imgFrame;
               cv::cvtColor(imgFrame, imgFrame, CV_BGR2RGB);
               QImage img;
               img = QImage((uchar*)imgFrame.data, imgFrame.cols, imgFrame.rows, QImage::Format_RGB888);
               QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(img);

               emit gottenVideoFrame(pixmap);
               if(recognizePerson==true)
               {
                   //write image to recognition buffer
                   recognitionThread->start();

                   if(myGlobalVariable==0)
                   {
                        frameForRecognition = imgFrame;
                        myGlobalVariable=55;
                   }

               }

               cv::waitKey(100);
           }
       }
  ```

webcamclass (AKA worker thread A) is a worker thread that creates a new worker thread implementing recognitionclass. (recognitionThread, AKA worker thread B)
Inside the recognitionThread I try to create a process to start my python virtual environment in my constructor. This works.
The error occurs at runtime at line containing successFailWrite = p.write("import imp...."); in the recognitionClass.cpp file on line 37.

My guess is that I am tryong to program this is in a very bad way which is why I am bumping from one problem into another. I already read other posts related to similar issues, but I was unable to find my way out.

Could someone please provide some explanation please?

Thanks!